# Recommendation for books about statistical data analysis with sparse data ( a lot of zeros)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, references, large-data, sparse

Evident from the title, i am looking for books about the general statistical data analysis techniques such as hypothesis testing, etc but for large and sparse dataset.